# How can I publish commands to the UR10/UR5?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ur10, universal-robots

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using the arm_controller/command topic, how can I publish valid commands to the UR10/UR5? Is there a list of example commands to send.

I'm trying to follow https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot setup for controlling a univeral robot in gazebo. My goal is to move the UR arm in simulation using joint position commands published through the terminal window (rostopic pub /arm_controller/command trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory). I'm able to launch the simulation following the repo's readme file. I'm not interested in using moveit or rviz to send commands.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360393/how-can-i-publish-commands-to-the-ur10/ur5?/) by [StewartHemm74](https://answers.ros.org/users/39655/stewarthemm74/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2020-08-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-26**:
I would suggest to add more information to your question: which driver are you using, how are you starting things, what configuration of the driver are you using, what is the type of `arm_controller/command` (we don't know), what is your goal (ie: pick-and-place, following a moving target, something else), etc, etc.

And *link to whatever you refer to*.

As-is, your question is too vague, and is hard to answer.

**Comment by [StewartHemm74](https://answers.ros.org/users/39655/stewarthemm74/) on 2020-08-26**:
I've added more details, attached links, and specified what my goal once in the updated question

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-26**:
Perhaps #q351835 can help here.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-01**:
Please do not delete questions with answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Refer to the folowing post: https://answers.ros.org/question/261081/cannot-create-trajectory-from-message-it-does-not-contain-the-expected-joints/

Answer deals with providing valid all joint names with the controller that the univeral robot manipulators use.

---

Originally posted by [StewartHemm74](https://answers.ros.org/users/39655/stewarthemm74/) with karma: 46 on 2020-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0